# Buy and sell products?

Tags: python, html, django

This app allows for bidding but I want someone who isn't logged in to not be able to bid and tell them they need to be logged in to be able to bid.
Even though I wrote the code in the function and the person who entered the site can make an offer, but it gives this error.
And how can I close the auction and introduce someone as a buyer?
Are the codes I wrote suitable for this?

error:

```
    Page not found (404)
    Request Method: GET
    Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/login/? 
     next=/build/1/
    Using the URLconf defined in commerce.urls, Django tried 
    these URL patterns, in this order:
    admin/
    [name='index']
    login [name='login']
    logout [name='logout']
    register [name='register']
    product_detail/<int:product_id>/ [name='product_detail']
    watchlist/<str:username>/ [name='watchlist']
    add/<int:productid>/ [name='add']
    remove/<int:pid>/ [name='remove']
    category/<str:name>/ [name='category']
    category_2 [name='category_2']
    create/ [name='create']
    build/<int:product_id>/ [name='build']
    accept/<int:product_id><int:bid_id>/ [name='accept']
    ^media/(?P<path>.*)$
    The current path, accounts/login/, didn’t match any of these.
```

models.py:

```
 class List(models.Model):
        choice = (
            ('d', 'Dark'),
            ('s', 'Sweet'),
        )
        user = models.CharField(max_length=64)
        title = models.CharField(max_length=64)
        description = models.TextField()  
        category = models.CharField(max_length=64)      
        first_bid = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)  
        image = models.ImageField(upload_to="img/", null=True)      
        image_url = models.CharField(max_length=228, default = None, blank = True, null = True)
        status = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices= choice)
        seller = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        winner = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, blank=True, 
               on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='winner')
        active_bool = models.BooleanField(default = True)

    class Bid(models.Model):
        product = models.ForeignKey(List, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        offered_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
```

views.py:

```
 def login_view(request):
     if request.method == "POST":

        # Attempt to sign user in
        username = request.POST["username"]
        password = request.POST["password"]
        user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)

        # Check if authentication successful
        if user is not None:
            login(request, user)
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("index"))
        else:
            return render(request, "auctions/login.html", {
                "message": "Invalid username and/or password."
            })
    else:
        return render(request, "auctions/login.html")


def logout_view(request):
    logout(request)
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("index"))


def register(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        username = request.POST["username"]
        email = request.POST["email"]

        # Ensure password matches confirmation
        password = request.POST["password"]
        confirmation = request.POST["confirmation"]
        if password != confirmation:
            return render(request, "auctions/register.html", {
                "message": "Passwords must match."
            })

        # Attempt to create new user
        try:
            user = User.objects.create_user(username, email, 
password)
            user.save()
        except IntegrityError:
            return render(request, "auctions/register.html", {
                "message": "Username already taken."
            })
        login(request, user)
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("index"))
    else:
        return render(request, "auctions/register.html") 
   
def product_detail(request, product_id):
        product = get_object_or_404(List, pk=product_id)
        comments = Comment.objects.filter(product=product)
        offers = Bid.objects.filter(product=product).order_by('-offered_price')
        
        context = {
            'product': product,
            'comments': comments, 
            'offers': offers,
            }
       if product.winner == request.user:
           messages.info(request, "Congratulations, you've won the auction!")
        return render(request, 'auctions/product_detail.html', context)

    @login_required
    def build(request, product_id):
        product = get_object_or_404(List, pk=product_id)
        if request.method == 'POST':
            user = request.user
            if user.is_authenticated:
                offered_price = Decimal(request.POST['offered_price'])
                if offered_price <= product.first_bid:
                    messages.warning(request, "Your offer must be greater than or equal to the original price.")
                elif Bid.objects.filter(product=product, user=request.user).exists():
                    messages.warning(request, "You've already made an offer for this product.")
                else:
                    Bid_ = Bid(product=product, user=request.user, offered_price=offered_price)
                    Bid_.save()
                    messages.success(request, "Your offer has been submitted.")
        return redirect('product_detail', product_id)

    @login_required
    def accept(request, product_id, bid_id):
        product = get_object_or_404(List, pk=product_id)
        offer = get_object_or_404(Bid, pk=bid_id)
        if request.user == product.seller:
            product.winner = offer.user
            product.save()
            # Notify the winning user here
            messages.success(request, "The product has been sold to {} for ${}.".format(offer.user.username, offer.offered_price))
        else:
            messages.warning(request, "You're not authorized to perform this action.")
        return redirect('product_detail', product_id)
```

urls.py:

```
path("", views.index, name="index"),
path("login", views.login_view, name="login"),
path("logout", views.logout_view, name="logout"),
path("register", views.register, name="register"),
path("product_detail/<int:product_id>/", views.product_detail, name="product_detail"),
path("watchlist/<str:username>/", views.watchlist, name="watchlist"),
path("add/<int:productid>/", views.add, name="add"),
path("remove/<int:pid>/", views.remove, name="remove"),
path("category/<str:name>/", views.category, name="category"),
path("category_2", views.category_2, name="category_2"),
path("create/", views.create, name="create"),
path("build/<int:product_id>/", views.build, name="build"),
path("accept/<int:product_id><int:bid_id>/", views.accept, name="accept")
```

product_detail.html:

```
    {% if product.winner == request.user %}
        <p>Congratulations, you've won the auction!</p>
    {% endif %}

    <h2>Your Bid:</h2>
    <ul>
        {% for offer in offers %}
            <li>{{ offer.user.username }} offered ${{ offer.offered_price }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>

    {% if not product.winner %}
        <form method="post" action="{% url 'build' product.id %}">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <label for="offered_price">Your Offer:</label>
            <input type="number" id="offered_price" name="offered_price" step="0.01" min="{{ product.price }}" required>
            <button type="submit">Submit Offer</button>
        </form>
   {% endif %}
```

Comment: You added a login_required decorator to your build and accept views, so Django will redirect to a login page, and while Django is redirecting, it couldn’t find the login url, that is what is causing the error. You will need to create your login url, you can also use Django’s built in authentication urls

Comment: @Temi If I have understood your meaning correctly, I must say that in View, a function is dedicated to logging into the system, and a URL has also been created, and because I thought it was not related to the question, I didn't include them.

Comment: Oh can you please share your log in  url and view.

Comment: @Temi Yes, please check the urls and view again.

Comment: Okay cool, can you go to your settings.py and set your LOGIN_URL = "login". Should work after this

Comment: @Temi How should I do it?

Comment: Go to your settings.py filte in your django project directory, and add LOGIN_URL = "login"

Comment: @Temi Yes, it worked. Thanks.
Can you guide me for the rest?